# What UX designers tools do you use?

Tags: tools, ux-designer

What tools are you using when creating a great user experience for mobile apps or websites?

I don't mean Mac/PC software like Axure or Balsamiq. I mean paper/pen tools. Do you use papers with mobile pattern or columns? Markers, crayons, sticky notes, Moleskine sketch, etc?

Comment: This isn't a solvable UX question with a correct answer, it's a poll / survey and as such doesn't fit with a Question and Answer website I'm afraid. You can try asking in [chat] but it's not a suitable question for the main site.

Answer (score 1):

Paper, pencil and ruler are good to go as they are time & cost effective.

Answer (score 1):

Paper and pen, colorizers, please some print outs of UX components. The print outs (for instance from Balsamiq) make it easier to ensure correct proportions.